# Substituir tudo após primeiro espaço em branco

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma variável que pode armazenar palavras compostas, como no exemplo abaixo. Gostaria de ajuda com o método `replace()` a fim de substituir ***tudo após o 1º (primeiro) espaço em branco***, não importa o conteúdo e o comprimento dele. Assim o valor da variável `phr` deixaria ser "stirred up", e passaria a ser "stirred", ***eliminando tudo a partir do 1º (primeiro) espaço em branco***, ou seja, " up" seria eliminado no dado exemplo. É importante que a eliminação seja realizada através do método `replace()`, pois ***o critério da substituição deve ser o 1º (primeiro) espaço em branco***. Desde já, agradeço a atenção.

```
var phr = 'stirred up';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar uma [expressão regular](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular?oldformat=true) no `replace`:

```
var phr = 'stirred up';
phr = phr.replace(/\s.*/, '')
// phr agora = "stirred"
```

O `\s` pega o primeiro espaço e `.*` pega todos os caracteres restantes da string.

Comment: Muito obrigado André. Exatamente o que eu procisava. Sua resposta foi muito útil.

Comment: @eden Se esta resposta lhe serviu, aceite-a para marcar o problema como resolvido.

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra forma de fazer, sem precisar usar expressões regulares, é a seguinte:

```js
var antes = 'stirred up';
var depois = antes.split(' ')[0];
alert("Antes: " + antes + "; Depois: " + depois);
```

Isso daí divide a string em vários pedaços usando os espaços como separadores (`'stirred up'` vai virar `['stirred', 'up']`) e então o `[0]` pega o primeiro elemento da string.